# Print media query not hiding class after preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a print preview library setup to show our users what the completed product will look like. The issue is that we don't actually want the images to print as we will be printing onto paper that is already branded.

I've added the print media query to the print.css and changed it so that all our images are being picked up and added to the class hideImg which exists in that print.css file.

I'm either looking for a reason why the print media query isn't working or how to alter the library / my jquery. I've tried adding them into different divs and changing what content is active on the preview but no luck.

The classes ARE being picked up and the console returns no errors.

**CSS :**

```
@media print {
/* -- Hide screen specific elements -- */
.hideImg{

    display:none !important;
    visibility:hidden !important;

        }
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
            var i;

                for(i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                    images[i].className += "hideImg";
                }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="content" class="container_12 clearfix">

     <div id="printableArea" style="display:none;">
        <img src="images/badgeHead.png" alt"needs more jpg"/>
                                      <h1>Hi, my name is...<br/> 
                                      </h1>

                                      <br>
         <img src="images/badgeFoot.png" alt"needs more jpg"/>
                                </div>    
</div>
```

**Library jQuery**

```
// Bind closure
            $('a', print_controls).bind('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //adding the printframe contentwindow rather than body prints out just what we want
                if ($(this).hasClass('print')) { print_frame[0].contentWindow.print(); }
                else { $.printPreview.distroyPrintPreview(); }
            });
```

Comment: What's `print_frame`? Also, if you're already using jQuery, why appending the `hideImg` class yourself, why not call `addClass('hideImg')`?

Comment: Also, if you're blindly appending `hideImg` to all `<img>` elements, why not simply use `img` as your selector in the print stylesheet?

Comment: Changing it to img in the print.css still doesn't make any difference.

Comment: That is some pretty funny looking jQuery you got there. But `images[i].className += "hideImg";` should be `images[i].className += " hideImg";`

Comment: It's a jQuery library for getting a preview of a printable area. It's indeed pretty funky and I need to look for an alternative for a production version.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in full screen and give print order. you can see check text in print order.

```css
@media print {
  /* -- Hide screen specific elements -- */
  .hideImg {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="container_12 clearfix">

  <div id="printableArea" style="display:none;">
    <img src="images/badgeHead.png" alt "needs more jpg"/>
    <h1>Hi, my name is...<br/> 
                                      </h1>

    <br>
    <img src="images/badgeFoot.png" alt "needs more jpg"/>
  </div>
  <div class="hideImg">hello</div>
  <h3>check</h3>
</div>
```